# How to edit eps-file by hands to insert cyrillic?

Tags: eps, cyrillic

I need to translate eps figure into cyrillic. And when i change strings into cyrillic's counterparts i got this:

[image]

What should i insert instead of cyrillic symbols?

Comment: Where's the topic relation to TeX?

Comment: @TeXnician well the book i'm currently translating is in TeX :) And i created this image with `latex`

Comment: If you created this image with `latex`, please add a MWE to help us help you.

Comment: Depends a bit on what you mean by "by hand". It looks like a font issue. In ps (or eps) you need to include the font, or at least font information. An alternative could still be to use `psfrag` to replace strings from LaTeX. It was a long time ago since I used it so I don't really remember how. But I think it is still alive.

Comment: We need to see a minimal working example.

Comment: @clemens Do you mean a picture as well? Any one of them is quite big.

Comment: @ Yola it doesn't matter any more since you've already found your solution :) but for future questions: if there is no code that can be copy-pasted and compiled than the vast majority of questions is rather hard to answer. From your question your problem wasn't immediatly clear and @StefanH had a lucky (but educated) guess…

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to StefanH for the suggestion i tried to use psfrag like this and it works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx,color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}
\thispagestyle{empty}

    % You can run this by typing the following commands:
    %    latex .tex
    %    dvips .dvi
    %    ps2pdf .ps

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\psfrag{valid}{чинний}
\includegraphics{figure.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the dvi file you should have like this, but in the ps and pdf files the text should be replaced in the picture.